# Google Directory API Search for a user by first name

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

Am using multiple domains on google apps for work, Am trying to develop a Python Script using API reference to google and search a name in all of the domains to see if the user exist in any one of the domain. The problem I am facing is to get the syntax to search for user by name.

Through the quickstart provided by google am able to pull down user list 
[link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#json-request)

what should I do to get the user by the name key, as per the reference give this list parameter can be used to search user by name.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: i have tried to get the user by get
`result = service.users().get(userKey='piyush')`
but it returns some memory location
<googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x000000000352E438>